# What form does Nyarlathotep take in Infestation?

Tags: comics, cthulhu-mythos, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles

In the recent TMNT Infestation mini-arc we are treated to one of the brain-shattering visages of Nyarlathotep. Is this form one of the ones taken [previously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyarlathotep#Table_of_forms)?

The form is mainly comprised of mouths and tentacles, so I'm tempted towards either *Bloated Woman* (post illusion removal) or *Howler in the Dark*.

Comment: Someone crossed TMNT with Lovecraft?  Now that's just sick.

Comment: @Tango actually, from an out-of-universe perspective, it makes a lot of sense to do that, since Lovecraft's works are all out of copyright in most (if not all) places. The same thing happened in Marvel comics with the introduction of characters from Norse mythology (Thor, Odin, etc.) - they took an existing public-domain body of content and adapted it into their own universe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out we saw Shub Niggurath instead of Nyarlathotep.

[image: Holy Crap! ....Shub Niggurath!]

How I missed that before. I don't know.

Comment: For what it's worth, Nyarlathotep *has* shown up in _TMNT_ before: Vol. I, No. 43, p. 37.

Comment: Iä! Shub-Niggurath! Iä!